# Unresolved "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 86-87: ordinal not in range(256)"

Tags: python, mysql

I have a bunch of english sentences that I am extracting from a text file to a MYSQL table. This is how I created my table in MYSQL:

```
create table sentences ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  sentence varchar (255) , primary key (ID) ) character set = utf8;
```

and this is my python script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
import sys
from fixsentence import *
import MySQLdb as db

bound = sys.argv[1]

con = db.connect('localhost' , 'root' , 'ayrefik1' , 'knowledgebase2')
curs = con.cursor()

def gettext(file):
        temp_file = open(file)
        soup = b(temp_file)
        list = get_sentences(soup.get_text())

        for x in list:
                curs.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
                curs.execute('insert ignore into sentences (sentence)  values (%s);', (x))
                con.commit()


gettext(bound)
```

And I run the script on a file in this way

```
python wikitext.py test
```

So even though I specified that the table should be able to handle all characters in UTF-8,
I still received this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 86-87: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: what type of data does the function get_sentences return? is it a list of unicode elements?

Comment: yes it returns a list of sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you use python 2.x, while executing of

```
curs.execute('insert ignore into sentences (sentence)  values (%s);', (x))
```

if x is an unicode object, python uses your console's default charset to encode it to a string . Assuming your default charset is latin-1 and this unicode object x contains non ascii characters, python will find it can't be encoded and throw the error. You have to convert x to a string manually with a specified charset, try this:

```
curs.execute('insert ignore into sentences (sentence)  values (%s);', (x.encode('utf-8'))
```